# Editing existing txt file in java

Tags: java, file, io

I have class Account which have username, fullName, password, id and points.
All accounts are saved in a file.I have many accounts in my file, not just one. This is example of one account in text file.

```
Miljan9602 Rakita Miljan miljan123 1463433398614 0.0
```

username, full name, password, id and points

Now, for example if i want to change points for my username. First thing i would do is go through all lines in file and compare all usernames, if i find equal username. I would change point's. This is my idea how to do it. Just dont know how to edit it in file.

```
public void edit(String username, double points)
{
    File f = new File("Accounts.txt");

    // file doesnt exist, return from method
    if(!f.exists())
        return;
    Scanner sc = null;

    try
    {
        sc = new Scanner(f);

        while(sc.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = sc.nextLine(); // Take whole line
            String split[] = line.split(" "); // Split it so i can check username

            if(split[0].equals(username))
            {
                String change = Double.toString(points); // Make string from double
                split[5] = change; // on fifth index are points

                /* My question is now how to edit file and to replace my new points
                 * with old points ?
                 *  Miljan9602 Rakita Miljan miljan123 1463433398614 0.0 <- Need to change this 0.0 with split[4];
                 */
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        // finally will always close file
        sc.close();
    }
```

Comment: Is each account's info written on its own line?

Comment: Each line is for each account. Is that what you are asking for ?

Comment: The sample data line does not have delimiters between fields.  How do you know where the fullname ends?

Comment: @JimGarrison My mistake. On split[5] are points, split[3] and split[4] is fullname

Comment: What happens if the fullname has more than 2 words, such as John Q Smith, or Jean Claude van Damme?

Comment: @JimGarrison Didnt think about that, but good example ! I will simply change " " to "_" and that will fix problem :)

Comment: You're better off using delimiters between fields.  This is called CSV (Comma Separated Value) format and there are good libraries for reading (parsing) and writing CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Apache's Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) library. Everything you'll need, and more, can be found there. Also, [here](https://github.com/apache/commons-io) is the GitHub mirror of Commons IO. Worth a look through.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
File f = new File("Accounts.txt");

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
// file doesnt exist, return from method
if(!f.exists())
    return;
Scanner sc = null;

try
{
    sc = new Scanner(f);

    while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = sc.nextLine(); // Take whole line
        String split[] = line.split(" "); // Split it so i can check username
        if(split[0].equals(username))
        {
            String change = Double.toString(points); // Make string from double
            split[5] = change; // on fifth index are points

            /* My question is now how to edit file and to replace my new points
             * with old points ?
             *  Miljan9602 Rakita Miljan miljan123 1463433398614 0.0 <- Need to change this 0.0 with split[4];
             */
            for(int i = 0; i < spit.length(); i++{
                fw.write(split[i] + " ");
            }
            System.getProperty("line.separator");
        }
    }
}catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    // finally will always close file
    sc.close();
    fw.close();
}
```

This should work

Comment: Could you be more detail please, i am not sure that i understand what you want me to do :)

Comment: Hmmm, it doesnt work. My file is empty after this code.

Answer (score 0):

As one has to write the entire read text back to the file system, use [Files.readAllLines()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-).

```
Path path = Paths.get(".../Accounts.txt");
Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
if (Files.exists()) {
    Files.readAllLines(path, charset);
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i) {
        String split[] = lines.get(i).split(" ");

        if (split[0].equals(username)) {
            String change = String.valueOf(points);
            split[5] = change; // on fifth index are points
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String value : split) {
                if (sb.length() != 0) {
                    sb.append(' ');
                }
                sb.append(value);
            }
            lines.set(i, sb.toString()); // Changes the line.
            Files.write(path, lines, charset);
            break; // leave loop
        }
    }
}
```

---

***More explained***

To alter a single line of a text file, one in principle has to load the entire text and after altering the line, safe it entirely.
The reason is that the file can shrink or grow, depending on the line changes.
Even with some twists this is not optimal.
`Files.readAllLines` is a nice method for that. One might also change the format:

- **Fixed length records (lines)** allow a RandomAccessFile. However a text risks being manually edited so the file gets corrupted, and one also has limited field lengths.
- The **.properties** format allows access with the Properties class. Requirement is a key, and a format `key = value`. Also the text has some escaping (`\`).

One could keep Accounts.txt in core, say in a class Accounts, representing all as a Map from user name to Account.

```
class Account {
    public final String userName; // Unmodifiable key
    public String password;
    ...
}
class Accounts {
    private Map<String, Account> accountsByUserName = new HashMap<>();
    public void loadAccounts() throws IOException { ... }
    public void saveAccounts() throws IOException { ... }
    public Optional<Account> getAccountByUserName(String userName) { ... }
    public void deleteAccountByUserName(String userName) { ... }
    public void createAccount(Account account) throws AlreadyExistsException { ... }
}
```

Comment: There is no other way just to edit current text file?

Comment: One could sequentially read a line and write it (possibly changed) back to _second_ file. And at the end substitute the files. All this is not scalable to large number of users, and quite brittle (if something goes wrong). Then you will want an embedded database like h2, Derby, ...